# Reverse lookup in a json string with key value pairs

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, reverse-lookup

I have a Pandas DataFrame, from a source that I can't change, in the following format:

```py
import pandas as pd

json_str_01 = '''[{"my_key": 1, "my_values": ["3_13"]}, {"my_key": 2, "my_values": ["3_18", "2_12"]}, {"my_key": 3, "my_values": ["2_10", "2_17"]}]'''
json_str_02 = '''[{"my_key": 1, "my_values": ["2_17"]}, {"my_key": 2, "my_values": ["2_12", "3_16"]}, {"my_key": 3, "my_values": ["3_13", "2_8"]}, {"my_key": 4, "my_values": ["3_18", "3_17"]}]'''

data = {
  "search_str": ["3_13", "2_8"],
  "json_data_str": [json_str_01, json_str_02]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Jupyter notebook snapshot of the DataFrame:

[image]

Each row has two columns, one is a string and the other is likely Json (I am not explicitly told that it is Json, but it can be parsed using Json libraries).

- The Json cell can have variable number of key-value pairs.
- Value is a list with one or more **string items**.

The *search_str* column corresponds to at least one of the **string items**. The task is to pull the corresponding key in a new column. To avoid any conflict in the future, the solution should return the first key in case of multiple matches.

The following code is giving the right results. I want to have a vectorized/optimized solution where I need expert input.

```py
def json_reverse_lookup(search_str, json_data_str):
    df_json_data = pd.read_json(json_data_str)

    for idx, row in df_json_data.iterrows():
        if search_str in row[1]:
            return row[0]
    
    return None

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: json_reverse_lookup(x['search_str'], x['json_data_str']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: @tdelaney I am checking for a string in a list of strings. I don't think it will return True for partial strings match.

Comment: @Oh, right. Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot vectorize this operation in an efficient way. Your best shot is most likely a python loop.

You could improve your code avoiding all pandas functions:

```
import json

def search_in_json(search_str, json_data_str):
    return next((d['my_key'] for d in json.loads(json_data_str)
                 for v in d['my_values'] if v == search_str), None)

df['result'] = [search_in_json(s, j) for s, j in
                zip(df['search_str'], df['json_data_str'])]
```

Output:

```
  search_str                                      json_data_str  result
0       3_13  [{"my_key": 1, "my_values": ["3_13"]}, {"my_ke...       1
1        2_8  [{"my_key": 1, "my_values": ["2_17"]}, {"my_ke...       3
```

Comment: Not me. I upvoted! actually, may have inadvertently downvoted previously as the downvote is gone after I upvoted.